# Disable header banner on specific Posts

Tags: custom-header

I Need to disable/block the header banner (Adsense code) on specific posts. I'm not a developer, I manually added the script in the `header.php`. Is there any way to disable that banner by specific post IDs? I would really appreciate any help I get in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the banner unavailable to certain posts by using if condition.

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
if ($post_id != idwheredisabled || $post_id != id2wheredisabled || .... ){
    Adsense code
}
```

if there are many ids then you can load them into an array and check if exists in array.

Comment: Thanks for responding Akshat! I would love to try this but where do I add this code?? I mean in the header.php or function.php? Sorry as I mentioned above I have no knowledge of PHP whatsoever.

Comment: As you mentioned in the question that you have placed the adsense code in header so you need to put this in header.php. you can replace idwheredisabled and id2wheredisabled with the id's where you want to exclude and .... if you want to add more post ids the you need to use $post_id != id3wheredisabled and so on.

Comment: Thanks a ton for explaining! I'll try the code and let you know if it works.

Comment: Hi again, I just tried it but it seems like I must have misunderstood something. '$post_id = get_the_ID();
if ($post_id != idwheredisabled || $post_id != id2wheredisabled || .... ){
    Adsense code
}' in that code "Adsense Code" part I used the adsense code i use in the header.. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: did you replaced idwheredisabled and id2wheredisabled with the post id where you want to exclude? and " || .... " is not proper code, you should use it if there are more id's if not then no.

Comment: Hi, Yes I did replaced 'idwheredisabled' with the post IDs but `$post_id = get_the_ID();
if ($post_id != MYPOSTID || $post_id != MYPOSTID2 || .... ){` this is showing up in place the header..

Comment: you need to know php, you should write php codes inside php tag, and remove  "|| ...." from the if statement, I wrote these characters just to make you understand that you can use n number of conditions